# Can I use Window.setLocationByPlatform() but give the launched window an affinity to its owner?

Tags: java, windows, swing

I have multiple screens, and a parent console window which JFrames are launched from. I want to use the default cascading algorithm a la Window.setLocationByPlatform(boolean), but it seems to default to one particular screen regardless where the parent console is.

Is there something I can change to make it launch in the same window as the parent, and still maintain the default cascading behavior?

My current setup has three screens. If the parent window is on screen 1, 2, or 3, the newly launched windows will always appear on screen 2.

Comment: hmmm are you heard about Desktop and JInternalsFrames http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/internalframe.html

Comment: Not an option. These need to be independent frames.

Comment: if you want ot manage something betweens http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html, then you have to use different Containers JFrame -> JDialog or JFrame - JWindow, from my experiences that isn't possible manage that easily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't look to be possible, and you just have to write your own using things like GraphicsEnvironment and GraphicsDevice. The methods getBounds(), and Rectangle.contains() does help a tremendous amount though.